# POSTGRESQL - Strategy on grouping a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
 u.creationtime::date as date,
 d.driver_statuses_city_id as id,
 u.usersid as applied
FROM 
users u 
JOIN 
driver_status d 
ON 
u.usersid = d.driver_id
WHERE 
(u.role = 'partner' or u.role = 'driver')
AND d.driver_statuses_city_id in 
(SELECT id FROM driver_statuses_city
WHERE city_id in ({{city_ids}}))
and u.creationtime::date > '2013-09-01'
```

Which outputs:

```
date          id      applied
2013-09-03   1121     2443122
2013-09-03   1122     2737622
2013-09-03   1123     2754122
2013-09-03   1122     2733422
etc           etc       etc
```

I want to group each id together by date. So that my output would look more like:

```
date                id                count(applied)
2013-09-03          1121                  1
2013-09-03          1122                  2
2013-09-03          1123                  1
```

But i am unsure of how to best display these. Would I be best inclined to use some sort of "case" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have your complete table structure but from what I can make out, it should be something like this:

```
SELECT 
 u.creationtime::date as date,
 d.driver_statuses_city_id as id,
 count(u.usersid) as applied
FROM 
users u 
JOIN 
driver_status d 
ON 
u.usersid = d.driver_id
WHERE 
(u.role = 'partner' or u.role = 'driver')
AND d.driver_statuses_city_id in 
(SELECT id FROM driver_statuses_city
WHERE city_id in ({{city_ids}}))
and u.creationtime::date > '2013-09-01'
group by date, id
```